# One ID shared between many requests in Spring

Tags: java, spring

I want to ask about something like `conversationId`, that could be shared between many requests/responses in one API call. For instance, we have `/test` endpoint, this endpoint call another service, then another and return response based on obtained results. It can looks like:

```
  Conversation:
  1) Sending test request.
  2) API calls /info endpoint.
  3) Returns /info response.
  4) API calls /example endpoint.
  5) Returns /example response.
  6) Returns /test response.
```

When we call `/test` API simultaneously 4-5 times, then log could be messy and we don't know how to combine the individual calls.

I want to tag it with any random request scope ID, like high value number. It could looks like:

```
  1) Sending test request of ID 12345.
  2) Sending test request of ID 98765.
  3) API calls /info endpoint of ID 12345.
  4) Returns /info response of ID 12345.
  5) API calls /info endpoint of ID 98765.
  6) API calls /example endpoint of ID 12345.
  7) Returns /info response of ID 98765.
  and so on
```

Is there any Spring mechanism to share data between `ClientHttpRequestInterceptor` and `GenericFilterBean` in request way without recreating those beans? Like a custom scope bean with lifecycle starts at `doFilter` and end there as well.

Comment: Probably, you can track the initial request and consecutive request/response with a cookie (conversationId).

Comment: @PeterMmm okay, but what about stateless connection without any cookies? I just want to "tag" any associated invocations

Comment: I think you can do this at the app level (without filter or interceptor). Your app receives /test request, then creates and starts a new client thread `new Client(conversationID)` and successive client threads that shares the same `conversationId`. As you say, HTTP is a stateless protocol, since you are not adding "something to identify" for every request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created `RequestContext` bean as a holder to my request data, such as `conversationId`:

```
@Component
@RequestScope
public class RequestContext {
    private final String conversationId;

    public RequestContext() {
        conversationId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

    public String getConversationId() {
        return conversationId;
    }
}
```

and, later, inject it into my Filter:

```
@Component
public class LoggingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private final RequestContext requestContext;

    public RestServerLoggingFilter(RequestContext requestContext) {
        this.requestContext = requestContext;
    }


...
}
```

but most important thing is configuration and order:

```
@Configuration
public class RestServerConfiguration {

    private static final int LOGGING_FILTER_ORDER = -104;

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean<RestServerLoggingFilter> initFilter(LoggingFilter filter) {
        FilterRegistrationBean<RestServerLoggingFilter> registrationBean = new FilterRegistrationBean<>();
        registrationBean.setFilter(filter);
        registrationBean.setDispatcherTypes(
                EnumSet.complementOf(EnumSet.of(DispatcherType.ERROR))
        );
        registrationBean.setOrder(LOGGING_FILTER_ORDER);
        return registrationBean;
    }

}
```

Filters are stacked into a list under `ApplicationFilterChain` class. When we browse this stack, we've got a `OrderedRequestContextFilter` bean with order `-105` that init `RequestScope` defining it's attributes at `initContextHolders`. It's very important to know about that. Then You can inject requested scope bean into any filter, that is after `OrderedRequestContextFilter` in chain.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [MDC](https://www.slf4j.org/api/org/slf4j/MDC.html?msclkid=22c99e07c6ce11ecb87a330a8823c0f3) along with [OncePerRequestFilter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/OncePerRequestFilter.html?msclkid=a53282c3c6d011ec882571939353344f) something like this for this kind of requirement.:

```
    @Component
    public class MDCFilter implements OncePerRequestFilter{
    @Override
        protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
            MDC.put("request_ID", someNumberGeneratorUtility());
            try {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            } finally {
                MDC.remove("request_ID");
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: It's a good thing, `OncePerRequestFilter` will do the thing and MDC can be used in our container per server request and response. Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Thanks @KurdTt-, just in case suggestion worked for you, you can accept the answer so that it will be helpful for community.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Using Sleuth**
(Limitation - Spring Cloud Sleuth is Spring Boot based)

Spring sleuth could provide trace ID, and span ID. Using trace ID you can combine the individual call.

The below example may be useful for someone.

**Add spring sleuth**

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

**Your /test**

```
        @GetMapping("/test")
        public String test() {

            LOG.info("Sending test request.");
            LOG.info("API calls /info endpoint.");
            // Calling /info service or endpoint
            LOG.info("Returns /info response.");
            LOG.info("API calls /example endpoint.");
            // Calling /example service or endpoint
            LOG.info("Returns /example response.");
            LOG.info("Returns /test response");

            return "test";
        }
```

**Calling /test API simultaneously 5 times and the server call log is shown below**

```
2022-04-28 00:40:11.108  INFO [test,be0b352e1f8664d1,be0b352e1f8664d1] 10766 --- [nio-9091-exec-5] c.k.d.d.a.AccountServiceApplication      : Sending test request.
2022-04-28 00:40:11.109  INFO [test,29c2e863354fca33,29c2e863354fca33] 10766 --- [nio-9091-exec-1] c.k.d.d.a.AccountServiceApplication      : Sending test request.
2022-04-28 00:40:11.115  INFO [test,29c2e863354fca33,29c2e863354fca33] 10766 --- [nio-9091-exec-1] c.k.d.d.a.AccountServiceApplication      : API calls /info endpoint.
2022-04-28 00:40:11.115  INFO [test,29c2e863354fca33,29c2e863354fca33] 10766 --- [nio-9091-exec-1] c.k.d.d.a.AccountServiceApplication      : Returns /info response.
2022-04-28 00:40:11.115  INFO [test,29c2e863354fca33,29c2e863354fca33] 10766 --- [nio-9091-exec-1] c.k.d.d.a.AccountServiceApplication      : API calls /example endpoint.
2022-04-28 00:40:11.115  INFO [test,29c2e863354fca33,29c2e863354fca33] 10766 --- [nio-9091-exec-1] c.k.d.d.a.AccountServiceApplication      : Returns /example response.
2022-04-28 00:40:11.115  INFO [test,29c2e863354fca33,29c2e863354fca33] 10766 --- [nio-9091-exec-1] c.k.d.d.a.AccountServiceApplication      : Returns /test response
2022-04-28 00:40:11.115  INFO [test,be0b352e1f8664d1,be0b352e1f8664d1] 10766 --- [nio-9091-exec-5] c.k.d.d.a.AccountServiceApplication      : API calls /info endpoint.
2022-04-28 00:40:11.116  INFO [test,be0b352e1f8664d1,be0b352e1f8664d1] 10766 --- [nio-9091-exec-5] c.k.d.d.a.AccountServiceApplication      : Returns /info response.
2022-04-28 00:40:11.116  INFO [test,be0b352e1f8664d1,be0b352e1f8664d1] 10766 --- [nio-9091-exec-5] c.k.d.d.a.AccountServiceApplication      : API calls /example endpoint.
2022-04-28 00:40:11.116  INFO [test,be0b352e1f8664d1,be0b352e1f8664d1] 10766 --- [nio-9091-exec-5] c.k.d.d.a.AccountServiceApplication      : Returns /example response.
2022-04-28 00:40:11.116  INFO [test,be0b352e1f8664d1,be0b352e1f8664d1] 10766 --- [nio-9091-exec-5] c.k.d.d.a.AccountServiceApplication      : Returns /test response
2022-04-28 00:40:11.109  INFO [test,b26d689f73b974b7,b26d689f73b974b7] 10766 --- [nio-9091-exec-4] c.k.d.d.a.AccountServiceApplication      : Sending test request.
2022-04-28 00:40:11.116  INFO [test,b26d689f73b974b7,b26d689f73b974b7] 10766 --- [nio-9091-exec-4] c.k.d.d.a.AccountServiceApplication      : API calls /info endpoint.
2022-04-28 00:40:11.116  INFO [test,b26d689f73b974b7,b26d689f73b974b7] 10766 --- [nio-9091-exec-4] c.k.d.d.a.AccountServiceApplication      : Returns /info response.
2022-04-28 00:40:11.116  INFO [test,b26d689f73b974b7,b26d689f73b974b7] 10766 --- [nio-9091-exec-4] c.k.d.d.a.AccountServiceApplication      : API calls /example endpoint.
2022-04-28 00:40:11.116  INFO [test,b26d689f73b974b7,b26d689f73b974b7] 10766 --- [nio-9091-exec-4] c.k.d.d.a.AccountServiceApplication      : Returns /example response.
2022-04-28 00:40:11.116  INFO [test,b26d689f73b974b7,b26d689f73b974b7] 10766 --- [nio-9091-exec-4] c.k.d.d.a.AccountServiceApplication      : Returns /test response
2022-04-28 00:40:11.109  INFO [test,4f28a79ecc2ce6da,4f28a79ecc2ce6da] 10766 --- [nio-9091-exec-2] c.k.d.d.a.AccountServiceApplication      : Sending test request.
2022-04-28 00:40:11.109  INFO [test,ee7bfa89b05b69ad,ee7bfa89b05b69ad] 10766 --- [nio-9091-exec-3] c.k.d.d.a.AccountServiceApplication      : Sending test request.
etc....
```

Notice that the application name is inside the brackets at the beginning. These brackets are added by Sleuth. They represent the application name, trace ID, and span ID.

**Also, You can get the current trace programmatically.**

```
        @Autowired
        private Tracer tracer;

        @GetMapping("/test")
        public String account() {

            LOG.info("Sending test request, " + "trace ID=" + tracer.currentSpan().context().traceId().toString());
            LOG.info("API calls /info endpoint, " + "trace ID=" + tracer.currentSpan().context().traceId().toString());
            // Calling /info service or endpoint
            LOG.info("Returns /info response, " + "trace ID=" + tracer.currentSpan().context().traceId().toString());
            LOG.info("API calls /example endpoint, " + "trace ID="
                    + tracer.currentSpan().context().traceId().toString());
            // Calling /example service or endpoint
            LOG.info("Returns /example response, " + "trace ID=" + tracer.currentSpan().context().traceId().toString());
            LOG.info("Returns /test response, " + "trace ID=" + tracer.currentSpan().context().traceId().toString());

            return "test";
        }
```

**Log**

```
....Sending test request, trace ID=51322ee614962951
.... API calls /info endpoint, trace ID=51322ee614962951
.... Sending test request, trace ID=4bc5017e2beceaf8
.... Sending test request, trace ID=75b638bda78a7bb5
.... Returns /info response, trace ID=51322ee614962951
.... API calls /info endpoint, trace ID=4bc5017e2beceaf8
.... API calls /example endpoint, trace ID=51322ee614962951
.... Sending test request, trace ID=f20cde67b4376777
  etc....
```

---

---

**2. You can use Thread Context Map**

```
        @GetMapping("/test")
        public String test() {
            ThreadContext.put("id", UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            LOG.info("Sending test request, " + ThreadContext.get("id"));
            LOG.info("API calls /info endpoint, " + ThreadContext.get("id"));
            // Calling /info service or endpoint
            LOG.info("Returns /info response, " + ThreadContext.get("id"));
            LOG.info("API calls /example endpoint, " + ThreadContext.get("id"));
            // Calling /example service or endpoint
            LOG.info("Returns /example response, " + ThreadContext.get("id"));
            LOG.info("Returns /test response, " + ThreadContext.get("id"));

            return "test";
        }
```

Comment: Unfortunely, It could be good, but I can't inject this bean into `GenericFilterBean`, I am using SpringBoot, something does not initialize my bean...?

Comment: Posting your sample code will give us a better picture.